# Perfect multicolinearity when x1+x2 = 1, and two observations

Tags: regression

I remember in econometric classes, one example we are often given about perfect multicolinearity is x1+x2 = 1. However, if we think about a dataset with two observations, `y1=2,y2=1` with two dummy variables `x1 = [1 0], x2 = [0 1]`. We can see that x1+x2 = 1, but in this two observation example, `X'X` is invertible. Did I miss anything?